# jtable - java - mysql -- Tamaño de tablas

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

soy nuevo en java y me surgió una duda, se puede crear tablas en donde por ejemplo: fila 1 tenga 3 columnas, fila 2 tenga 5 columnas y asi! no tengo codigo es una duda ya que quiero hacer algo asi y no vi nada al respecto, y finalmente la idea es volcar esa info de la tabla en base de datos(mysql)! Gracias!

Comment: La pregunta no tiene ninguna relación con Java. Te sugiero que elimines las etiquetas java y netbeans.

Comment: no soy experto en java, por lo cual no voy a discutir tu sugerencia, pero lo q consulto es si se puede armar la tabla con Jtable de java con un cierto formato... y luego volcar esos datos de la tabla a mysql... por lo q creo si tendria q ver con java y agregue netbeans por uso el mismo(el cual podria si eliminar dicha etiqueta)

Comment: con respecto a la respuesta que me brindaste fue muy buena y agradezco mucho tu info! muchas gracias!

Comment: Ah ok, es que no haces referencia al JTable, hablas de tabla y luego de MySQL, de ahí mi sugerencia. Tu siempre podrás volcar los datos de cualquier componente (en este caso un JTable) a una o varias tablas de una base de datos, pero siempre tienes que respetar la estructura de la base de datos.

Comment: si tenes razon no hice refencia al jtable, muy clara tus respuestas! Ahora suponiendo que utilice mongoDB para poder tener la flexibilidad que necesito, luego en java podre armar un jtable de tal manera? mucha gracias!

Comment: No, en el JTable, al igual que las tablas de las bases de datos relaciones, todas las filas tienen la misma cantidad de columnas, lo que puedas es dejar las columnas que no utilices en cada fila vacías.

Comment: muchisimas gracias, todo aclarado! soy nuevo en la pagina, tilde tu respuesta ... no se si asi ya esta elegida...gracias nuevamente!

Comment: Así está perfecta. Un saludo y un placer haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En un sistema de bases de datos relacionales como MySQL no es posible hacer lo que indicas. En este tipo de sistemas de bases de datos, todas las tuplas(filas) de una misma tabla tienen la misma estructura (entiéndase cantidad de columnas y tipo de cada una). Si necesitas este tipo de flexibilidad te recomendaría utilizar una base de datos tipo NoSQL (Not only SQL), como MongoDB, que si permiten hacer exactamente lo que preguntas.